# How to disable debug logs in spring shell(cli)?

Tags: java, spring

I use spring shell (not spring boot) in my app and want to disable debug logs.

After I run commands console print some debug logs. For example:

> "DEBUG - DefaultListableBeanFactory     - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'myPromptProvider'"
>
> "DEBUG - DefaultListableBeanFactory     - Returning cached instance of singleton
> bean 'defaultPromptProvider'"

Note that i run my app in windows cmd with `java - jar *.jar`

Here is my code:

```
@Component
public class Test implements CommandMarker {

//------------------------------------------------------ create
@CliCommand(value = {"test"})
public void test(
        @CliOption(key = {"str"}, mandatory = true) final String str
) {
    System.out.println(str);

}
}
```

and here is output:

```
spring-shell>test --str aaa  
aaa  
  
DEBUG - DefaultListableBeanFactory     - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'defaultPromptProvider'  
DEBUG - DefaultListableBeanFactory     - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'myPromptProvider'
```

I want to eliminate those debug lines.

Comment: `This question is not duplicate` - What is the significance of this line?

Comment: @ vinS: Can you answer my question?

Comment: May be this post will help you - http://forum.spring.io/forum/other-spring-related/shell/745973-spring-shell-startup-and-shutdown-logs

Comment: I did that right now. but its not works.